# How to convert input arguments to program as json in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
import json
import sys

def main():
    payloads=sys.argv[2]
    payloads=payloads.replace(",",",\"")
    payloads=payloads.replace(":","\":")
    payloads=payloads.replace("{","{\"")
    z=json.loads("'"+payloads+"'")
    print(payloads)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The input can not be changed as its auto generated and I need to parse it inside the python code to get individual values. How can this be done, p.s. I am not python expert

When i try to run it in command prompt as below (in single line):

```
python test.py payload: "{"temperature":20,"humidity":80,"pressure":1000,"timestamp":1652419592750,"deviceid":"device1"}"
```

I see below error:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 10, in main
    z=json.loads("'"+payloads+"'")
  File "python3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "python3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "python3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: You need to put the argument in single quotes, not double quotes. Otherwise, the double quotes in the JSON will delimit the argument strings.

Comment: Thats what the replace is doing, also the input comes as double quotes from calling app

Comment: Why are you concatenating single quotes to `payload` when calling `json.loads()`? Single quotes aren't part of JSON syntax.

Comment: If you do the quoting properly you wouldn't need to do all those replaces.

Comment: Hi @Barmar As i said the input comes from some other application

Comment: JSON example is there in the code

Comment: You cannot control the invocation? The other application calls your script via the command line and passes the JSON incorrectly?

Comment: It's simply wrong on the calling side. You're being passed garbage. It's madness to try to fix that garbage afterwards. The calling side should be fixed to pass values correctly.

Comment: You are right @deceze the other application is node-red , I can not change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easyest way to solve your problem would be to add good quotes to the input but if you can't, you can use this

```py
import json, sys

def main():
    payloads=sys.argv[2]
    payloads=payloads.replace(",",",\"")
    payloads=payloads.replace(":","\":")
    payloads=payloads.replace("{","{\"")


    for x in payloads.split(","):
        
        value = x.split(":")[1].replace("}", "")

        try:
            int(value)
            float(value)
            assert value not in ("true", "false", "null")

        except (AssertionError, ValueError):
            new = x.replace(value, f'"{value}"')
            payloads = payloads.replace(x, new)

    
    z=json.loads(payloads)
    print(payloads)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

note however that this way can cause a lot of bugs if your input data ever contains the characters `}`, `:` or `,`

Comment: This worked fine, i am not expecting any of { : or , in my input for sure

Comment: This works only for string values, I have excluded bool, int, float ans none values

Answer (score 2):

Put single quotes around the argument, then all the double quotes will be preserved, and you don't need to do any replacing in Python.

```
import json
import sys

def main():
    payloads=sys.argv[2]
    z=json.loads(payloads)
    print(payloads)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
python test.py payload: '{"temperature":20,"humidity":80,"pressure":1000,"timestamp":1652419592750,"deviceid":"device1"}'
```

Comment: I can not change the input to program, this is mentioned in the question

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. I just had to add `import sys`

Comment: What does `print(sys.argv[2])` show?

Comment: If you can't change the input, you're screwed. When all the quotes are removed from the JSON, there's no way to know where they originally were and put them back.

Comment: i already imported sys, will update question, here is output of print 
{temperature:20,humidity:80,pressure:1000,timestamp:1652419592750,deviceid:device1}

Comment: That's not valid JSON since all the quotes are missing. Like I said, there's no reliable way to add back the quotes.

Comment: What OS are you using? This works on Unix.

Comment: If you pass proper JSON, you don't have to do anything, it's already JSON.

Comment: You're not adding quotes around `device1`.

Comment: so there is no way to handle it, as only for string values quotes needs to be added

Comment: Not any general way. If you happen to know the exact format of the JSON, you can write ad hoc code to fix it.

Comment: Why python is removing quotes from program arguments?

Comment: Python isn't removing anything. The shell uses the quotes to delimit strings in the arguments. The argument that's passed to the program is the resulting string between the quotes.